# Microsoft Access list box is empty even though RowSource is specified and returns results

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I created a ListBox in a form. Its RowSource is being filled by VBA, but the ListBox is empty.

When I open the Query in the RowSource, Access returns rows, but the ListBox itself is empty. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

[image]
<sup>**list box is empty**</sup>

[image]

Comment: To help attract answers, could you please include a code snippet? And welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you state:

> Its RowSource is being filled by VBA, but the ListBox is empty.

You may need to `Requery` the list box after modifying the content of its Row Source -

```
ListBoxName.Requery
```

Change `ListBoxName` to suit the name of your control.

You may also want to check that the **Column Width** is non-zero.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. It is really weird, because it is working on a different form. Regardless of this, shouldn't the ListBox display results, if the query is valid, when I reopen the form? Nonetheless it's still empty..

Comment: @jo-el Is the Column Width property non-zero?

Comment: Okay, I managed to solve the problem. Seems like there was a problem with the query. I needed to use Art = true instead of Art = 1 when specifying it in the RowSource. Even though it works as a normal query, it doesn't seem to work as a RowSource.

Comment: You could also have used `Art = -1` since `True` evaluates to `-1` in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a problem with the query. The Column "Art" was defined as a boolean. Even though it should work when querying it with 1, when specified as a RowSource, it needed to be queried with true instead. Querying it with 0 works though. Anyways, thanks for all your help!